# Umbraco 11 Shared hosting

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, content-management-system, hosting, umbraco

Any umbraco 11 experts here? trying to host a fairly small umbraco site for cheap with shared hosting cant find any useful guides or reputable hosting providers that account for umbraco 11 thanks :)

Tried hostinger & hostgator both pretty useless imo

Comment: Please see my answer below and remember to upvote/accept the useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Azure to host all my Umbraco v7, v8, v10 and v11 websites. You can create an Azure account and purchase cloud services that you need [at pay-as-you-go pricing.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/purchase-options/pay-as-you-go/)

A typical Umbraco v11 CMS project will require the following Azure Setup at minimum.

- Subscription
- Resource group
- App Service plan for the BO website
- App Service plan for the FE website
- App Service for the BO website
- App Service for the FE website
- SQL server and SQL database

On top of these, you should create a storage account to store media, application insights for both your websites and whatever else you need. You can check the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/?product=popular) for more details.

Bonus note: You can alternatively look at [Umbraco Cloud](https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-cloud/) or [Umbraco Heartcore.](https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-heartcore/). Please check [this article](https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2022/choosing-umbraco-products-for-clients/) to look at the differences between all these Umbraco products, but in short;

Umbraco Heartcore is the headless SaaS CMS offering of Umbraco. It comes without a presentation layer and you are 100% free to choose how to implement your presentation layer. Quite a lot of agencies prefer to develop the Front-end website with a powerful front-end JavaScript framework, e.g. Vue, Nuxt, Svelte, React or NextJS.

Umbraco Cloud is the semi-SaaS (Software as a Service) offering of Umbraco with an ASP.NET MVC front-end website that needs to be implemented by the Developers.

Coupled Umbraco CMS is the free Umbraco CMS offering. The latest version is v11 and it is built on the latest .NET 7 technology. Umbraco Forms need to be purchased.

I recommend Microsoft Azure for your Umbraco CMS projects. Azure is a cloud computing service operated by Microsoft for application management via Microsoft-managed data centres. It provides SaaS, PaaS, and IaaS options.

For the “Coupled Umbraco CMS on Azure Cloud” option, I recommend moving away from Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) solutions to Platform as a Service (PaaS) solutions, e.g. stopping using VMs and starting using Azure App Services etc.